# Do I need to redirect my CDN subdomain www version to the non-www

Tags: seo, redirects, dns, subdomain, cdn

I just uploaded some images to a CDN that is available under:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/image/filename.jpg
```

So I need to make any redirect as I do for the main domain? In that case I redirect the non-www version to the www version and it's the preferred URL in Webmaster tools.

Is it the same for subdomains? I mean do I have to create a CNAME for the `http://www.subdomain.example.com` and redirect it to `http://subdomain.example.com` or I'm fine with only the non-www version?

What is the proper SEO friendly workaround here? Do I need to care about the ww version of the CDN subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to redirect a CDN since Google will not treat resources as page content and therefore if resources are accessible in several ways it will have no bearing on the page. You should use the URL that you prefer to use and put this to rest.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Simon's answer...

Is `www.subdomain.example.com` even accessible? There's no point creating a CNAME record for `www` just so you can redirect it. Users aren't expecting `www.subdomain.example.com` to be available in the same way they might expect `www.example.com` to be (but neither are they likely to type it).